# Вызов одной функции в разные промежутки времени

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом вызвать func_call(), в разные промежутки времени?

```
def func_call(a, b):
    print(a + b)

def f1():
    while True:
        func_call(1, 2)
        time.sleep(3)

def f2():
    while True:
        func_call(2, 3)
        time.sleep(10)

f1()
f2()
```

Comment: Используйте потоки или асинхронность.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под вызовом функции в разные промежутки времени? Функции должны вызываться параллельно? Или этот промежуток времени должен быть различным, а не 3 секунды как указали вы в коде?

Comment: С одним набором данных вызываю функцию раз в 3 сек. постоянно, а с другим набором данных раз в 10 сек. постоянно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам уже подсказали, используйте мультипоточность:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def func_call(a, b):
    print(a + b)

def f1():
    while True:
        print('Func f1')
        func_call(1, 2)
        time.sleep(3)

def f2():
    while True:
        print('Func f2')
        func_call(2, 3)
        time.sleep(10)

thread1 = Thread(target=f1)
thread2 = Thread(target=f2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```